# keyboard arrows as input source

Tags: c++

Can someone explain the first part of this code and how to enable the using of std i/o instead of having to limited scopes. Thanks in advance. and what is the wincon.h library?
I am trying to get input from the keyboard arrows (navigators)

```
‪#‎include‬ <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <wincon.h>
void main ()
{
    HANDLE hInput = GetStdHandle(STD_INPUT_HANDLE);
    DWORD NumInputs = 0;
   DWORD InputsRead = 0;
   bool running = true;
   INPUT_RECORD irInput;
   GetNumberOfConsoleInputEvents(hInput, &NumInputs);
   while(running)
   {
   ReadConsoleInput(hInput, &irInput, 1, &InputsRead);
   // std::cout << irInput.Event.KeyEvent.wVirtualKeyCode << std::endl;
   switch(irInput.Event.KeyEvent.wVirtualKeyCode)
   {
   case VK_ESCAPE:
   running = false;
   //Quit The Running Loop
   break;
   case VK_LEFT:
   case VK_NUMPAD4:
   // move it left
   std::cout << "left";
   break;
   case VK_UP:
   case VK_NUMPAD8:
   // move it up
   std::cout << " up" ;
   break;
   case VK_RIGHT:
   case VK_NUMPAD6:
   // move it right
   std::cout << "Right";
   break;
   case VK_DOWN:
   case VK_NUMPAD2:
   // move it down
   std::cout << "down";
   break;
   }
   }
   system ("pause");
   }
```

Answer (score 3):

The C style standard console I/O is what's called "cooked", meaning that the input does not reach the application until it has been buffered and is complete (the user hits enter). To do "raw" I/O from the console involves using system-specific functionality. In this case, the `ReadConsoleInput` function, and related functionality.

Unfortunately, it's quite difficult to allow arrow-keys and similar, and at the same time use the standard I/O functions. It is probably possible to do in most environments, but there is typically no direct exposure of the required functionality - in other words, you can't "get to" the bits that you would have to modify to allow this - you either end up writing your own I/O functionality, or you use the "standard method". Depending on what you are actually trying to achieve, one or the other will be the "right" solution. It's impossible to say without knowing what sort of application you are doing and what you are trying to actually achieve.

As far as I can tell, `wincon.h` in this case is completely superfluous, and shouldn't be needed (and I don't think `conio.h` is required either). The posted code also completely uselessly calls `GetNumberOfConsoleInputEvents` - it would be useful to call this to check how many key-presses there are waiting in the input queue if you want to do something like "is a key pressed", where you don't want to wait for keyboard input.

What the code does:

```
HANDLE hInput = GetStdHandle(STD_INPUT_HANDLE);
```

Fetch the handle for the low-level console standard input.

```
DWORD NumInputs = 0;
DWORD InputsRead = 0;
bool running = true;
INPUT_RECORD irInput;
GetNumberOfConsoleInputEvents(hInput, &NumInputs);
```

Fetch number of "events" for the console - in other words, how many keypresses there are "waiting". Since this information is not used anywhere, it's pretty pointless in this particular example.

```
while(running)
{
   ReadConsoleInput(hInput, &irInput, 1, &InputsRead);
```

Read one input from the console. (You should check that `InputsRead` contains 1 after this, and check the return value from `ReadConsoleInput`, just to be sure).

```
   // std::cout << irInput.Event.KeyEvent.wVirtualKeyCode << std::endl;
   switch(irInput.Event.KeyEvent.wVirtualKeyCode)
```

Use `switch` to distinguish different keys.

Comment: thank you very much for your help, really appreciated. I din't write the code myself, I was trying to find a way to use the keyboard arrows to get an input to move the cursor up and down along a list in a game I am working on, and this is what I found on cplusplus.com so I wanted to ask. If you can suggest any other way that is easier or more clear, please do and thanks in advance

Comment: The functions in your question are fine for reading "raw" keyboard input. The problem comes with "mixing" the standard input.